# How to get Magento Store Details in a PHP Array by Store ID?

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a function which takes store id and return a PHP array which have the store details like store name, store code, logo, banner, name etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this it will work...

```
public function get_storedetails($store) {
     $res = array();
     try {
         $res["store"] = Mage::app()->getStore($store);
         Mage::app()->setCurrentStore($store);
         $res["storeid"] = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getStoreId();
         $res["storecode"] = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getCode();
         $res["storewebid"] = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getWebsiteId();
         $res["storename"] = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getName();
         $res["storeactive"] = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getIsActive();
         $res["rooturl"] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);            
         $res["storeurl"] = Mage::helper('core/url')->getHomeUrl(); 
         $res["storelogo_alt"] = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_alt');             
         $res["storefrontname"] = Mage::app()->getStore($store)->getFrontendName(); //getLogoSrc()           
         $res["current_url"] = Mage::helper('core/url')->getCurrentUrl();
         $res["media_url1"] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_LINK);
         $res["media_url2"] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
         $res["skin_url"] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN);
         $res["js_url"] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS);          
         $res["storelogo"] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_SKIN).'frontend/default/default/'.Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src');
         $res["storeadminname"] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/name');
         $res["storeemail"] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_sales/email');             
     }
     catch(Exception $ex) {
         echo $ex;
     }
     return $res;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks Shashi It is working as i needed.

Answer (score 3):

you can get a store details like this:

```
$store = Mage::getModel('core/store')->load($storeId);
$code = $store->getCode();
$name = $store->getName();
```

You can do this to see what data you can get from the store object

```
var_dump($store->getData())
```

The logo and other settings you need to get from the config section.

```
$logo = Mage::getStoreConfig('design/header/logo_src', $soreId);
```

This way you can get all the information from the config. You just need the correct path.  For this you can see the name of the input field from system->configuration and section name and build the path.
Let's analyse the logo. You can find it in the `Design` tab and the url  looks like this: 'admin/system_config/edit/**section/design**'. So the first part of the path is the section name `design`.
The  field name is `groups[header][fields][logo_src][value]`. Just remove `groups`, `[fields]` and `[value]` and you get the rest of the path `header/logo_src`.